# .sock file not appearing in project directory with gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am trying to set up gunicorn for my web server, and I am currently following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04#create-a-gunicorn-systemd-service-file

The problem is that gunicorn has not generated a **myproject.sock** file in the directory of my project.

My configuration in this file: `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service`, looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=daniel
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/daniel/myproject
ExecStart=/home/daniel/myproject/myproject_venv/bin/python3 home/daniel/myproject/myproject_venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 -b :8000     myproject.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am using Django from Digital Ocean for my web server, so right at the very start, the server came with files and directories such as `django/django_project/django_project`.
But instead of using the already-made files, I created a new project with new directories (Just as the tutorial said).

When looking at the gunicorn error logs, with `sudo journalctl -u gunicorn`, at the top, it says:

`Listening at: unix:/home/django/gunicorn.socket (1915)`

As previously stated above, I made a new project with different directories than the ones with **django**,  so I am looking for a way to change where gunicorn is listening to. Specifically, I want it to listen at `home/daniel/myproject/myproject.sock`.

Unfortunately, **myproject.sock** doesn't exist for some reason.

my project files are owned by a sudo user and group, so that unicorn has access.
The WorkingDirectory should be correct.

I would appreciate any help, as I am very new to nginx, unicorn and django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `-b :8000` try `--bind unix:/home/daniel/myproject/myproject.sock`. I haven't used gunicorn myself, but I'm guessing that it's binding to tcp port 8000 right now.

Comment: This answer and some reviewing of the template for `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service` fixed the problem for me. Many thanks!